# Visual studio 2015 get bower dependies folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015

i'm trying to create an empty project with the `dependencies` folder and the `www` folder,
Isn't there any project with only these folders?

This is now generated via http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

but this has a lot of junk files imho, I could delete them, but I would think there would be an easier way to get those folders in your project

[image: folder]

Answer (score 0):

apparantly wans't fully awake clicking the following did the trick:

[image: clickedy]